# Inclusion of Sobolev spaces in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, interpolation

I want to show that for $s\in[0,n/2)$ and $p \in [2,2n/(n-2s))$ we have the following (continuous) inclusion
$$
H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n).
$$

I have tried to find two interpolation pairs between Sobolev and $L^p$ spaces using Riesz-Thorin and interpolation theorem for sobolev spaces, but nothing has worked out. Maybe I am not using the right coefficients.
Any hint or reference would be very appreciated!

Edit: I have proven the fact that Sobolev space of a certain rank can be embedded into $C_0^N$ (for some N). To use interpolation results I need now that $H^{n/2} \subset L^q$ for $0<q<2n/(n-2s)$.

Comment: What you are looking for is a (fractional) Sobolev embedding. You can look up Theorem 6.7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it but since I am seeing this as an example for interpolation methods, I am trying to follow that path.

Comment: So you know the result for integer values of $s$ and you want to use it to extend the result to fractional values of $s$? This is possible indeed.

Comment: The problem is that I have the result only for $L^\infty$.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include all the results you know from which you wish to derive the one you desire.

Comment: One cannot deduce this from interpolation since the embedding does not hold for the extremal point $p=\infty$. Except if you know the result with BMO and know the interpolation of Hardy spaces ...